# using a media query to only target tablet and dektop

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to use the NOT operator in media queries

like this

```
.media{
    @media screen and not (max-width: 600px){
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: stretch; 
    }
}
```

but its not working, i am getting an error, any clue anyone

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

```css
    @media screen :not(media) (max-width: 600px){
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: stretch; 
  }
```

Comment: its not compiling in .scss, i tried it gives me an error